# Is there a way to output a list of Metamask account names and addresses?

Tags: metamask

Using Metamask with multiple 'accounts'.  Is there a way to output a simple list of account names and addresses?

For example...

| Account Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Account1 | 0x123... |
| Account2 | 0x4ab... |
| Account3 | 0x34a... |
| MyHeadHurts | 0x2n1... |

Thanks in advance.